# Meaning of いなくもない

Tags: translation

I am not sure about いなくもない in the following sentence:

「私の尋ねていることにちゃんと答えなさい」と腹をたてる人もいなくもない。
I guess the meaning is that people react pissed when someone tells them to just answer the question(s), but I am bit unsure about いなくもない.

Does it mean something like 'sometimes people might react angry when they are told to just answer the question'?

Answer (score 6):

The meaning of the sentence is approximately the opposite of your interpretation, namely

> Some people get angry and say "Answer my question properly"

いなくもない means something like "it's not that there isn't", or more idiomatically "there are some".

I think what confuses you about the meaning of the sentence is と. Here it is the quotative particle, not the if/when と. If you wanted to convey your interpretation, one option would be

> 「私の尋ねていることにちゃんと答えなさい」*といわれると* 腹をたてる人もいなくもない。

Comment: Thanks. Yes it was the particle and double-negation nai+mo that confused me. Thx.